# Removing a view from a SuperView on iOS 4 SDK

Tags: iphone, navigation, view

I'm developing an iPhone 3.1.3 app with iOS 4 SDK.

I have two ViewControllers, mainViewController and AboutViewController.

I use this code to go from mainViewController to AboutViewController (code inside mainViewController.m):

```
- (IBAction) aboutClicked:(id)sender
{
    AboutViewController* aboutController =
        [[AboutViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController"
                  bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutController.view];

    [aboutController release];    
}
```

And this to come back from AboutViewController to mainViewController (code inside AboutViewController.m):

```
- (IBAction) backClicked:(id) sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When I click on Back Button on AboutViewController, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I'm using a window-based application template.

I've also tried to add a breakpoint in `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` but I can't.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS is because after adding the view of a viewController as sub view you released the controller, hence the touch event couldn't see the intended viewController to process it.

comment out the release statement like below and it should work

```
- (IBAction) aboutClicked:(id)sender
{
    AboutViewController* aboutController =
    [[AboutViewController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController"
              bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:aboutController.view];

//[aboutController release]; To avoid leaking consider creating aboutController variable at instance level and releasing it in the dealloc.
}
```

Comment: @Cyprian you are right, but i was just trying to point which memory release is causing the error, hoping question owner will put alternate mechanism to manage this memory. Now, i updated my answer to caution this.

Comment: This is the right answer. If I release ViewController, I will get a SIGABRT exception. You are right!! Thanks a lot! @Cyprian, you must consider to remove your -1 point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
- (IBAction) aboutClicked:(id)sender
{
    AboutViewController* aboutController =
        [[AboutViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController"
                  bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:aboutController animated:YES];

    [aboutController release];    
}
```

And this to come back from AboutViewController to mainViewController (code inside AboutViewController.m):

```
- (IBAction) backClicked:(id) sender
{
    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works, but... do you know why fails my code?

Comment: It should work fine, you should try using Zombies to find out the exact problem. My guess you are overreleasing something in your dealloc method in the AboutViewController. If zombie want show you what happens, try instruments they are much better at pinpointing that. I usually get this error when I allocate autoreleased UI component like UIButton and then try to release it in the dalloc method of my view controller. I provided you this solution cause it's more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self presentModalViewController:aboutController animated:YES];
```

To present the view and:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To remove the view...

Comment: Some times I had problems with the animated:YES in the presentModalViewController try animated:NO

Answer (score 0):

1) Make aboutController a class level variable

2) Create a delegate method to handle

`(IBAction) backClicked:(id) sender`

3) In implementation of delegate call

```
 [aboutController.view removeFromSuperView];
```